# What's the best way to implement Windows Authentication for an ASP.NET MVC intranet application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 4 application which previously used Windows Forms to authenticate users, but I'm moving it to an internal server and would like to authenticate users based on their AD logon and using Windows authentication.

Within my database, I have a list of users AD usernames (domain\username) and some basic permissions. If a user attempts to access the application, and they're in the database, I'd like to grant access and assign their permissions. If they're not in the database, I'd like to grant access, but only assign them basic permissions (read-only).

What's the best way to implement the authentication (without rewriting the application to use simple membership)? (Or is that really the best way!?)

Any help is appreciated - every articles points to simple authentication or naming users in the web.config.

Comment: There are basically two parts in this. First is Authentication and then comes the Authorization. For Authentication you might want to see this **[link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs)**. Then comes in the Authorization part which would be using the Authorize Attribute which keeps a check on which user has access to which Action methods in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest writing a custom attribute to handle this:

```
MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Check database here
    }
}
```

Then have all your controllers inherit from a base controller that has the authorization attribute on it:

```
 [MyAuthorization]
 public class BaseController : Controller
 {
 }

 public class HomeController : BaseController
 {
      //Do Stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) to provide Authentication and then modify the database to align with the [SimpleRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to provide Authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at using LDAP, it's pretty straight forward to get up and running and the calls are quite simple.